# Groovy - Ambigous handler methods

Tags: java, spring, rest, groovy, spock

I write REST api in Java and test using Groovy and Spock.

Methods in my controller:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> findById(@PathVariable Long id) {
        final ExampleObj dto = service.findById(id);
        if (dto != null) {
            return new ResponseEntity<ExampleObj>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
        }
        return new ResponseEntity<ExampleObj>(dto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }

@GetMapping(value = "/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> findByName(@PathVariable String name) {
    final ExampleObj dto = service.findByName(name);
    if (dto != null) {
        return new ResponseEntity<ExampleObj>(dto, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<ExampleObj>(dto, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
}
```

And my test in Spock:

```
@Unroll
    'findByName test'() {
        when:
            def response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, ExampleObj)
        then:
            response.getStatusCode() == statusCode
        where:
            url                                 | statusCode
            '/endpoint/SomeName1'           | HttpStatus.OK
            '/endpoint/NotExistingName'    | HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

    }

@Unroll
    'findById test'() {
        when:
            def response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, ExampleObj)
        then:
            response.getStatusCode() == statusCode
        where:
            url                 | statusCode
            '/endpoint/1'    | HttpStatus.OK
            '/endpoint/2'    | HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND

    }
```

And when I run test I get the following exception:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Ambiguous handler methods mapped for HTTP path 'http://localhost:35287/endpoint/SomeName1': {public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ExampleController.findByName(java.lang.String), public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity ExampleController.findById(java.lang.Long)}

Comment: it just can't decide which method to call because both linked to the same path `/`

Comment: sorry I edited a question

Comment: no. the problem is in `@GetMapping(value = "/{id}")` and `@GetMapping(value = "/{name}")`. there is no difference in those url's. for example: `/111` - how mapping should identify what to call `/{id}` or `/{name}` ?

Answer (score 1):

Spring can not differentiate between "/{id}" and "/{name}". It really is ambiguous, because even if name is a String and id is a number, name can be of the form "43" too. So when you call "/43" it can be interpreted as a name (string "43"), and as a long too (43).

You can use instead something like:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> findByName(@RequestParam("name") String name) {
...
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you'll need to somehow differentiate the URL's. Eg

```
@GetMapping(value = "/id/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> findById(@PathVariable Long id) { ... }

@GetMapping(value = "/name/{name}")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> findByName(@PathVariable String name) { ... }
```

Or you could do the routing yourself. Eg:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/{value}")
public ResponseEntity<ExampleObj> find(@PathVariable String value) {
    try {
        long id = Long.parseLong(value);
        return findById(id);
    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        return findByName(value);
    }
}
```